# How to make Tag cloud in Word 2007 quickly?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Those tag clouds are generated dynamically, not in Word or any other program. As such it would be painfully hard to duplicate the effect.

Comment: @Grammar Perhaps the asker is just trying to create a mock-up in Word for some other purpose.

Comment: Then screenshot it and use it as a picture. There isn't a practical way to do this without a lot of formatting to get it look just right.

Comment: That is a valid suggestion; I think you should post it as an answer so it can be seen and voted on.

Comment: Please add some information on what you already tried to do and any other specifications you might have

Comment: @gareth how did you find old images back

Comment: Guys, he probably just wants to generate the graphics out of predefined words....he does not need it to be populated dynamically as on websites

Answer (score 4):

I would use [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net/), then take a screenshot and paste it in word:

> Wordle is a toy for generating “word clouds” from text that you
>   provide. The clouds give greater prominence to words that appear more
>   frequently in the source text. You can tweak your clouds with
>   different fonts, layouts, and color schemes. The images you create
>   with Wordle are yours to use however you like. You can print them out,
>   or save them to the Wordle gallery to share with your friends.

Comment: this is something of a real solution to the problem...

Answer (score 2):

Because of how the tag cloud is generated (dynamically, on the fly) it would be extremely tedious to replicate in a word processing program.

If you need this for a demo or layout, I suggest using a screen shot of the tag cloud instead of trying to recreate it manually.

Answer (score 1):

1. Write out all the tags. Make them the right font and color.
2. Double-click each word in turn to select it and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> grow the font size.
3. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>,</kbd> to shrink the font size.

Another option is to use the "Format Painter" feature of Word. Instructions for using this feature in [Word 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/HA010548921033.aspx) or [Word 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA100905271033.aspx?pid=CH100970211033) make it look like you can use this to copy the formatting from one word and paste it on to each of the other words.  This might be a faster method than editing the font size and color on each individual tag.

Comment: and is there any shortcut to change color like from dark to light.

Comment: I found the "Format Painter" feature which can do both at the same time.  I recommend using that feature instead.  Added to my answer.

Comment: how to use Format painter in Word 2007?

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA100905271033.aspx?pid=CH100970211033